# Android TableLayout group dynamic radioButtons

Tags: java, android

How can I group all dynamic created radioButtons into one group?

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
     // CheckBox chk = new CheckBox(this);
      RadioButton  radioBtn =  new RadioButton(this);
     // chk.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("from_text")));
      radioBtn.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("from_text")));
      radioBtn.
      row.addView(radioBtn);
      table.addView(row);
}
```

**Xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

        <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myTable"/>         
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle radio buttons as a group they have to be placed into a `RadioGroup` layout. If you are going to place the radio buttons in separate table cells instead then you'll have to implement the group behavior yourself.

You can use [RadioButton.SetOnCheckedChangeListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener%28android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener%29) to register a listener that responds to checked events.

You can look at the [RadioGroup source code](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/widget/RadioGroup.java.htm) to see how this is done with the RadioGroup layout.